# Call Javascript function on receiving ajax response in JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf

I'm using JSF 2.0 and it's new (actually old, but now incorporated in JSF) ajax features.

I have something like this:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{coordinatesMBean.name}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Reverse me!">
  <f:ajax execute="name" render="reverseName"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputText id="reverseName" value="#{coordinatesMBean.reverseName}"/>
```

It works fine, after hitting button value from inputText is sent to server, put into managed bean, and `reverseName` is rerendered with new data.

What I want to do is not only rerendering `reverseName`, but also call some Javascript function when ajax response is received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<f:ajax>` has `onevent` and `onerror` attributes. Give them a try.

Alternatively, Richfaces `<a4j:support>` has the `oncomplete` attribute for that purpose.

Comment: I think oncomplete is what I need. onevent is fired when request is sent to server, before response is received and handled, right? So it's not good for me.

Comment: Ok, onevent is triggered 3 times, with different statuses:
1. when ajax request is sent to server (I don't remember the status)
2. when response is received (status = complete)
3. also when response is received (status = success)